# Sharepoint: hiding Approve/reject element from item's context menu

Tags: sharepoint

Is there a way to hide "Approve/reject" item from item's context menu on Sharepoint? I don't want to disable approving at all, because it will delete "Approval status" column for example - i only want to hide this item from the menu. There is a node "HideCustomAction" available in CustomActions.xml, but I don't know if it can be of any use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How to: Hide a Menu Item in the ECB from SharePoint List Items"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768565.aspx